# Order a collection by relational belongtomany fields

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I've an **Event** model with belongtomany **Date** model

```
public function dates () {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Date', 'event_date');
}
```

Every Date have a start and an end date.

### Es:

Event->name = StackOverflow Meeting

Event->dates() =

[0] ('start' => 01-24-2018, 'end' => 01-27-2018)

[1] ('start' => 04-24-2018, 'end' => 04-27-2018)

---

Event->name = Easter Party

Event->dates() =

[0] ('start' => 04-18-2018, 'end' => 04-19-2018)

---

I want to order events by start date based on today date, 
so in the example "Easter Party" is the first event because have the first start date > today date. Then:

('Easter Party', 'StackOverflow Meeting')

How can I manage to create an order of this kind?

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier if every event has its own dates right in the table?!

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `event` relation into a `Date` model I think you can do

```
// Get dates with event, sort by start date 
$datesWithEvents = Date::whereBetween($yesterday,$today)->orderBy('start')->with('event');

// you can Extract only events
$event = $datesWithEvents->pluck('event'); // I think you need to add "->with('event')" into the return event method on Date Model
// or directly return dates with events
return $datesWithEvents;
```

Comment: Thanks is a good idea, I have to do some tests, but I do not understand why you used the whereBetween ($ yesterday, $ today), I simply have to discard the past dates (<today).

Comment: ok, I thought you needed to filter by date.  You can remove or put another method

Comment: Uhm... My actual query is something like $events = Event::where('status', '=', 1)->with('dates', 'categories', 'promoters')->get(); // how to take also categories and promoters in your event pluck?

Comment: I cannot mark as best answer because it seems that I can't pluck in a relational method. Pluck looking for field "event" on dates table, then I got "column not found" error. In belongtomany relationship there are a pivot table.

Comment: I made a comment on that line. I'm not testing but I think that if you add `->with('event')` into the relation method, will work. If not tell me and i'll remove that option. Was only one idea

Comment: Nevermind it seems to work now... I made some other test to try other info on the query.